# Is there a script or methodology to turn C# code into a graph representation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml, graphviz

Since Visual Studio only supports modeling of software (reverse engineering of a current design) does any one know or can anyone suggest of a way to take C# code and transform it into a graph representation?

I would think this would be a straightforward thing to do. As long as you can define what certain software components would align to what "shape" would it not be informative and useful function to see how different components fill out the scheme?

Wouldn't it be as simple as creating a set of regular expressions that transform the code into graphviz notation?

Comment: C# is more complex than can be parsed with regular expressions. The suggestion to use the native tools, or the Roslyn compiler to get a machine readable representation sounds like better choices.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio includes functionality for this - mainly the [Class Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Visual Studio 2012, Update 1 also adds a [Code Map](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/26/introducing-code-map-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-ctp.aspx) feature, which transforms your code into a different visual representation, and allows you to view "diagrams" built at the method call level.

Comment: Is this feature for Ultimate only? I am looking for a solution that will work with any version of VS

Comment: @n8CodeGuru You can create in Ultimate, and view in Pro+

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) you should be able to produce an abstract syntax tree which you could then use to feed your graphviz